# Django DRF validation on GET method

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I suppose that DRF framework / django has a better way to do that.

```
class Providers(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        from .doctor_search_helper import DoctorSearchHelper
        from .gmaps_helper import GMapsHelper

        localizacao = request.query_params.get("localizacao", None)
        especialidade = request.query_params.get("especialidade", None)
        plano = request.query_params.get("plano", None)
        tipo_estabelecimento = request.query_params.get("tipo_estabelecimento", None)
        distancia_maxima = request.query_params.get("distancia_maxima", None)

        if (not localizacao) or (localizacao == ""):
            return Response({"error": "localizacao is required"}, status=400)
        if (not especialidade) or (especialidade == ""):
            return Response({"error": "especialidade is required"}, status=400)
        if (not plano) or (plano == ""):
            return Response({"error": "plano is required"}, status=400)

        if (not plano) or (plano == ""):
            return Response({"error": "plano is required"}, status=400)

        if (not distancia_maxima) or (distancia_maxima == ""):
            return Response({"error": "distancia_maxima is required"}, status=400)
```

Do DRF has any library that supports validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django-Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Example code:

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from myapp import Product
from rest_framework import generics


class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    localizacao= filters.CharField(field_name="localizacao", required=True)
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['localizacao', 'max']

class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

It does have its own [Validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validators), to be used together with `serializers` when you are trying  to validate some generic data possibly related to some `Model`.

Although, in your case you are just trying to validate the presence of some query string parameters in your request. And, I believe the right place is in the view, just as you are doing.

That being said, your code is rather redundant. The condition chaining is always the same, one possible way to clean up the view is to gather the information you want to validate into one object and then loop through:

```py
class Providers(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        params = {        
            'localizacao': request.query_params.get("localizacao", None),
            'especialidade': request.query_params.get("especialidade", None),
            'plano': request.query_params.get("plano", None),
            'tipo_estabelecimento': request.query_params.get("tipo_estabelecimento", None),
            'distancia_maxima': request.query_params.get("distancia_maxima", None)
        }

        for key, value in params.items():
            if not value or value.strip() == '':
                error_message = f'{key} is required'
                return Response({"error": error_message}, status=400)

        return Response({"message": "all params are present"}, status=200)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no library in DRF that supports validation. You'll have to write custom code for request fields validation.

You could also write serializer class to validate request fields parameters.